# All of the series used in a model must be stationary at the same order of differencing

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, cointegration, vector-autoregression

While practicing VAR analysis, all of the series used in the model must be stationary at the same order of differencing. Is this correct?

For example, let $X$~$I(1)$ and $Y$~$I(2)$. Can I use these two series for VAR analysis?

Comment: You can run a VAR on $\Delta X$ and $\Delta^2 Y$. Also, $X$ and $\Delta Y$  may be cointegrated; then a VECM on $X$ and $\Delta Y$ could be employed.

Comment: ok. i can run both Var and Cointegration analysis. thank you @RichardHardy